# What is the general method for easily solving these type of expressions? $(a+b)/(a-b)$

Tags: arithmetic

$\dfrac{a+b}{a-b}$.
the particular expression in my case is:

$$
\frac{20 \sin(x)-1}{20 \sin(x)+1}
$$

the value of $\sin x$ is $\dfrac{100}{\sqrt{1000^2-100^2}}$ so it's very hard to do it by simple arithmetic.

Comment: $\sqrt{1000^2-100^2}=\sqrt{100^2(10^2-1)}=100\sqrt{99}=300\sqrt{11}$ so in the end $\sin(x)=\cfrac{1}{3\sqrt{11}}$ which is no longer so very hard to work with directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we have that
$$\frac{a-b}{a+b}=\frac{a+b}{a-b}\frac{a-b}{a-b}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{(a+b)^2}$$
and that
$$\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)^{-1}=\frac{(a+b)^2}{a^2-b^2}$$